# Batch Script: Using GOTO on IF statement

Tags: batch-file

When you get to the user input part, no matter what I type (desk, fire, door) it always goes to fireplace. Is there something wrong with my if syntax?

```
    @echo off
    color C
    title RG Text Game
    echo -------------------------------------------------
    echo Welcome to the Game!
    echo.
    echo -------------------------------------------------
    echo.
    pause

    echo.
    echo Blah bah blah story story
    echo What do you want to do?
    echo Choices: fire/desk/door
    set /p choice= 
    if %choice%=="fire" GOTO fireplace
    if %choice%=="desk" GOTO desk
    if %choice%=="door" GOTO door

    :fireplace
    echo.
    echo You come to the fireplace.
    echo.
    pause

    :desk
    echo.
    echo You go to the desk.
    echo.

    :door
    echo.
    echo You go to the door.
    echo.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doublequote `%choice%` or it will not be equal: `desk` is not equal as `"desk"`.

And exit your `Label` block with a `goto:eof` or `exit/b`.

Use the `/i` switch with `IF` so you can also use `DESK` or `DesK`

```
 if /i "%choice%"=="fire" GOTO fireplace
 if /i "%choice%"=="desk" GOTO desk
 if /i "%choice%"=="door" GOTO door
 goto:error

:fireplace
echo.
echo You come to the fireplace.
echo.
pause
exit/b

:desk
echo.
echo You go to the desk.
echo.
exit/b

:door
echo.
echo You go to the door.
echo.
exit/b
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to protect the entry points of each of your target blocks, otherwise when it's done executing the target block, it will "fall into" the next block.

Before any label line (e.g., `:fireplace`), you'll need a `GOTO` to make sure that the program flow doesn't "fall into" the next routine:

```
@echo off
color C
title RG Text Game
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo Welcome to the Game!
echo.
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo.
pause

echo.
echo Blah bah blah story story
echo What do you want to do?
echo Choices: fire/desk/door
set /p choice= 
if /I "%choice%" EQU "fire" GOTO fireplace
if /I "%choice%" EQU "desk" GOTO desk
if /I "%choice%" EQU "door" GOTO door
GOTO END

:fireplace
echo.
echo You come to the fireplace.
echo.
pause
GOTO END

:desk
echo.
echo You go to the desk.
echo.
GOTO END

:door
echo.
echo You go to the door.
echo.

:END
```

Note also the changes to the `IF` statements. These allow you to handle the case of typing `FIRE` or `Fire` instead of just `fire`.

Comment: This immediately ends my program regardless of what I type. So maybe it's not taking my input at all?

Comment: I've edited the response to address those errors, which **I** overlooked as well. You need to quote the variable as well as the string you're comparing, and the `/I` allows the comparison to be case-insensitive. [`HELP IF`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) can be helpful reading. You might also want to look at [`HELP CHOICE`](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the tips from Jeff and SachaDee,
if you name all your labels equal to the choice you could use a loop

```
For %%A in (fire desk door) Do If /i "%choice%" equ "%%A" Goto %choice%
```

Or with a llimited number of choices you could use choice.exe and work with a single letter answer (no enter needed then) and evaluate the returned errorlevel.